# Count # of unique values for dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have created nested dictionary with values extracted from error logs.

ErrorTypes are "Msg" and "Cmd"

```
dict1 = {
    '1234': [
        ['2014-09-19 09:55:41', 1234, 'Msg', 'N/A', 'N/A'],
        ['2014-09-19 10:22:22', 123, 'Msg', 123, 'N/A'],
        ['2014-09-19 12:22:21', 1234, 'Cmd', 123, 'N/A']
    ]
}
```

What is the code for how I can get a count so I know how many of each error type exists for each key?

This is what I have so far:

```
from collections import Counter

dict2 = {}
for k in dict1:
        for v in k:
                dict2[str(k)].append(str(k),collection.Counter(v[k] for v in dict1))
```

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could walk through the list of lists and make a `set` of error types, then just check the length of that set. Sets, by definition, may only contain unique items so you will not have repeats.

```
dict1 = {'1234': [['2014-09-19 09:55:41', 1234, 'Msg', 'N/A', 'N/A'],
                  ['2014-09-19 10:22:22', 123, 'Msg', 123, 'N/A'],
                  ['2014-09-19 12:22:21', 1234, 'Cmd', 123, 'N/A']]}

>>> set(i[2] for i in dict1['1234'])
set(['Msg', 'Cmd'])

>>> len(set(i[2] for i in dict1['1234']))
2
```

To make the dictionary you described in your comment

```
dict1 = {'1234': [['2014-09-19 09:55:41', 1234, 'Msg', 'N/A', 'N/A'],
                  ['2014-09-19 10:22:22', 123, 'Msg', 123, 'N/A'],
                  ['2014-09-19 12:22:21', 1234, 'Cmd', 123, 'N/A']],
         '5678': [['2014-09-19 09:55:41', 1234, 'Foo', 'N/A', 'N/A'],
                  ['2014-09-19 10:22:22', 123, 'Bar', 123, 'N/A'],
                  ['2014-09-19 12:22:21', 1234, 'Bar', 123, 'N/A']]}

from collections import Counter

>>> {key : Counter([i[2] for i in dict1[key]]) for key in dict1.keys()}
{'1234': Counter({'Msg': 2, 'Cmd': 1}),
 '5678': Counter({'Bar': 2, 'Foo': 1})}
```

Comment: Is there a way to create another dictionary so that the format of the dictionary would look like this:

dict2 = {'1234': {'Cmd':3, 'Msg':2}, '2345': {'Cmd':2, 'Msg' 5}}